# How can I install Nginx 1.8.0 on SMP Debian 7 (3.2.81-1)

Tags: debian, apt, nginx

I am using a cloudserver. I installed Debian 7 (minimal) from the hosting company's image. Logged in as root.

I have added the following to the bottom of my /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ wheezy nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ wheezy nginx
```

Then I downloaded the nginx key, and added it to my apt key chain.

I then ran the following commands

```
apt-get update
apt-get install nginx
```

The system still installed nginx 1.10.1

I understand this is because Debian has an 'approved' list of packages and the only 'approved' version is 1.10.1

But by adding Nginx to the sources.list and updating my apt-get, I was lead to believe this would allow me to download a more up to date version of nginx.

I have followed 4 seperate tutorials today and haven't been able to get any of them to work.

Can someone please tell me the commands I need to execute to upgrade my nginx to 1.8.0 i would be most grateful. I am trying to install this exact version 1.8.0 as I am working on a development box, and trying to replicate the production enviornment as closely as possible and it's using 1.8.0.

Thanks

Comment: Because you selected the nginx repo you have downloaded the latest and greatest stable version (1.10) which is _newer_ than the old 1.8 version.  http://blog.andrewbeacock.com/2007/03/how-to-install-specific-version-of.html may help you with how to install specific versions

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to [Stephen Harris](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/168757/stephen-harris) for providing me this solution. He posted the link to this blog http://blog.andrewbeacock.com/2007/03/how-to-install-specific-version-of.html which had a very simple solution to my problem.

First I ran the following command

```
apt-cache showpkg <package name>
```

In this case

```
apt-cache showpkg nginx
```

Then I searched the output of this for the version of nginx I was trying to install (1.8.0). It had a specific title in the list, in this case: -

```
1.8.0-1~wheezy
```

Then I removed nginx (this wasn't in the instructions but it seemed sensible to do this) I used the following command, I had picked up from my many attempts earlier: -

```
apt-get purge nginx nginx-common
```

Then I ran the apt-get install again but this time appended the exact version I had found in the previous step above, like so: -

```
apt-get install nginx=1.8.0-1~wheezy
```

I then ran the following command

```
nginx - v
```

To verify my installation which was indeed now...

```
nginx version: nginx/1.8.0
```

Thanks again to Stephen Harris for sharing the solution originally provided by [Andrew](http://blog.andrewbeacock.com/2007/03/how-to-install-specific-version-of.html)